# Why is yylval null?

Tags: bison, yacc, lex, flex-lexer

I'm trying to write my first parser with Flex & Bison. When parsing numbers, I'm trying to save their values into the `yylval` structure. The problem is, `yylval` is null when the lexer reaches a number, which causes a segmentation fault.

(Related point of confusion: why is it that in most Flex examples (e.g. [here](http://epaperpress.com/lexandyacc/)), `yylval` is a structure, rather than a pointer to a structure? I couldn't get `yylval` to be recognized in test.l without `%option bison-bridge`, and that option made `yylval` a pointer. Also, I tried initializing `yylval` in `main` of test.y, but `yylval = malloc(...)` gives a type mismatch-- as if `yylval` is *not* a pointer...?)

test.l

```
%{
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include "svg.tab.h"
%}

%option bison-bridge
%option noyywrap

%%

[0-9]+  { yylval->real = atof(yytext); return REAL; }

. { return *yytext; }

%%
```

test.y:

```
%{
    #include <stdio.h>
    void yyerror(char *);   
%}

%union {
    double real;
}

%token <real> REAL

%%
...
```

Build command:

```
bison -d test.y && flex test.l && gcc lex.yy.c test.tab.c
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Normally, `yylval` is a global struct and not a pointer, and if you remove the `%option bison-bridge` from your test.l file, that's what you get (you'll need to change `yylval->real` to `yylval.real` as well to make it work).

The `%option bison-bridge` in flex is meant to match up to `%define api.pure` in bison, which uses a different API for communicating between yyparse and yylex (yylval becomes a pointer argument to yylex instead of a global var).

So your basic problem is an incompatible API between flex and bison -- you need to specify the pure api/bison-bridge in BOTH or NEITHER -- if you do it in one and not the other, things break.