# Can't retrieve semantic values from Bison grammar file

Tags: c, parsing, bison, flex-lexer

I am trying to develop a language parser on CentOS 6.0 by means of Bison 3.0 (C parser generator), Flex 2.5.35 and gcc 4.4.7. I have the following Bison grammar file:

```
%{
#include <stdio.h>
%}

%union {
  int int_t;
  char* str_t;
}
%token SEP
%token <str_t> ID
%start start
%type <int_t> plst

%%

start: plst start
     | EOS              { YYACCEPT; }
;
// <id> , <id> , ... , <id>
plst: ID SEP_PARAMS plst    { printf("Rule 1 %s %s \n",$1,$2); } 
    | ID            { printf("Rule 2 %s \n", $1); }
    | /* empty */       {  }
;

%%

int yyerror(GNode* root, const char* s) {printf("Error: %s", s);}
```

#### The problem

As it is now, it is not really a meaningful one, but it is enough to understand my problem I think. Consider that I have a scanner written in Flex which recognizes my tokens. This grammar file is used to recognize simple identifier lists like: `id1,id2,...,idn`. My problem is that in each grammar rule, when I try to get the value of the identifier (the string representing the same of the identifier), I get a `NULL` pointer as also proved by my `printf`s.

What am I doing wrong? Thankyou

## Edit

Thanks to recent answers, I could understand that the problems strongly relates to Flex and its configuration file. In particular I have edited my lex file in order to meet the specifications described by the [Flex Manual](http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/Bison-Bridge.html) for Bison Bridging:

```
{ID}     { printf("[id-token]");
           yylval->str_t = strdup(yytext);
           return ID; }
```

However after running Bison, then Flex (providing the `--bison-bridge` option) and then the compiler, I execute the generated parser and **I instantly get `Segmentation Fault`**.

What's the problem?

Comment: You do set the correct union fields in the lexer?

Comment: ehm... I do not know what you are talking about... I import in the lex file the .tab.h file generated by bison if this is what you mean...

Comment: Should I show the lex file as well? Is it related?

Comment: Found an answer for my edit thanks to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6432549/why-is-yylval-null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The values for `$1`, `$2` etc. have to be set by the lexer.

If you have a rule in the lexer for identifiers, like

```
ID       [a-z][a-z0-9]*

%%

{ID}    { return ID; }
```

the semantic values are not set.

You have to do e.g.

```
{ID}    {   /* Set the unions value, used by e.g. `$1` in the parser */
            yylval.str_t = strdup(yytext); 
            return ID;
        }
```

Remember to `free` the value in the parser, as `strdup` allocates memory.

Comment: Well, I do not do this... OK, gonna fix and let you know about. Thanks

Comment: Freeing can be done by simply using the following line right: `free($1)`?

Comment: Sorry, but here http://flex.sourceforge.net/manual/Bison-Bridge.html it is said that `yylval` evaluates to pointer... so it should be `yylval->str_t =...` right?

Comment: It is strange.. I do exactly as said here: http://flex.sourceforge.net/manual/Bison-Bridge.html, but I get segmentation fault...

Answer (score 2):

The flex option `--bison-bridge` (or `%option bison-bridge`) matches up to the bison option `%define api.pure`.  You need to use either BOTH `bison-bridge` and `api.pure` or NEITHER -- either way can work, but they need to be consistent.  Since it appears you are NOT using `api.pure`, you want to delete the `--bison-bridge` option.